# A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool

Tags: performance, connection, c3p0

we use c3p0 as connection pool

we have this error :

> 2023-10-25T**12:55:34.162** [INFO]  thread:[pool-9-thread-7          ]
> [ApplicationVersion:[83.0.4-4021]
> DiagnosticKey:**[e4b904f6-a77c-4001-93ac-cf562153faf3]** ReferenceCode:[]
> ClientMachine:[127.0.0.1] RemoteIp:[] RemotePort:[]]
> c.t.s.e.TransactionExecutorThreadingManager.run@53:   New thread is
> created from : 5a62c616-df3f-4b9d-99b4-74a70edf5d49  , new thread info
> : pool-9-thread-7, 184

> 2023-10-25T**12:55:34.174** [DEBUG]
> thread:[pool-9-thread-7          ] [ApplicationVersion:[83.0.4-4021]
> DiagnosticKey:**[e4b904f6-a77c-4001-93ac-cf562153faf3]** ReferenceCode:[]
> ClientMachine:[127.0.0.1] RemoteIp:[] RemotePort:[]]
> o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.getTransaction@366:     **Creating new
> transaction with name [ExternalTransaction]:
> PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT**

> 2023-10-25T**12:55:36.482**>  [TRACE] thread:[pool-9-thread-7          ]
> [ApplicationVersion:[83.0.4-4021]
> DiagnosticKey:[e4b904f6-a77c-4001-93ac-cf562153faf3] ReferenceCode:[]
> ClientMachine:[127.0.0.1] RemoteIp:[] RemotePort:[]]
> c.m.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.log@187:    trace
> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@227dcf **[managed: 45,
> unused: 0, excluded: 0]** (e.g.
> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@5cbc0787)

> 2023-10-25T**12:55:41.551** [DEBUG] thread:[pool-9-thread-7          ]
> [ApplicationVersion:[83.0.4-4021]
> DiagnosticKey:**[e4b904f6-a77c-4001-93ac-cf562153faf3]** ReferenceCode:[]
> ClientMachine:[127.0.0.1] RemoteIp:[] RemotePort:[]]
> com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.log@198:      Converting Throwable to
> SQLException... com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: **A client
> timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from
> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@227dcf -- timeout at
> awaitAvailable()**    at
> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1461)
> at
> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:639)
> at
> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:674)
> at
> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:674)
> at
> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:674)
> at
> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:674)
> at
> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:674)
> ...

It seems that the program try to get connection from pool but after 5 seconds (according to checkoutTimeout) time out. the pool has 45 busy connections  more than 200 free connections .

Comment: Just above in the log it shows 45 total connections, zero unused. you might be leaking Connections, or the pool might just be badly oversubscribed.

Comment: The managed connections we see in the log are connections checked out, and  unused connections are the connections checked in, isn't it ? In this scenario, the max pool size is 300, and at the other time in the log, we have more than 100 managed connections.  @SteveWaldman

Comment: No. The managed Connections are the total managed by the pool, unused are those currently available for checkout. (Excluded are checked out connections that will be destroyed rather than reused on checkin.) If your maxPoolSize is 300, then c3p0 should be trying to acquire new Connections. perhaps there are failed acquisition attempts in your logs too. Or perhaps your effective config isn't what you think.

Comment: Re your immediate issue, you can always make `checkoutTimeout` bigger, or don't set it at all. Then instead of this prompt-ish failure, you'd see either slow successes (if the issue is just overload), or indefinite hangs (if you have a `Connection` leak and what you are really experiencing is pool exhaustion).